# Can I repair this cold water hose?

Tags: plumbing, water, hose, fitting

I am trying to fix tap that has a leaky hose that leaks where 3/8 nut is. It leaks only when I move the nut. Presumably because I over-tightened it last time.

I went to Lowe's and Home Depot and they did not have a replacement hose because of the unconventional 1/8 brass pipe fitting end that goes into tap.

[image]

[image]

The questions I have:

1. **Is it possible to repair such hoses by replacing just the rubber seal on the 3/8 compression fitting end? If yes, what part do I need to fix it?**
2. **Any other tricks to try so that I could avoid to replace the tap?**
3. **Home depot plumber told me it is 1/8 brass pipe fitting, but is it really true? On [amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01A6LFOWG) I found visually similar hose where other end was called M10 connector. So which one of these two is it?**

Update#1: Here  is close up. It leaks just behind the nut where arrow points. Leak gets worse if I wiggle the hose.

[image]
[image]

Comment: if it leaks from that crack that's not the  where the seal is, the seal is between the fixed part of the hose and whatever it connects to, the nut is just to maintain pressure.  can you show a photo looking into the leaky end on an angle?

Comment: @Jasen I uploaded picture. Let me know if it is good.

Comment: I want to see the opposite view,  what your granite bench would see.

Comment: @Jasen. Done. There is damaged black rubber seal. There were small parts that were separated.

Comment: yeah, you need to replace that seal, and make sure the surface it presses against is clean level and smooth. it should be possible to extract the seal with a pointed tool, (pin or nail etc) and  find a replacement at the hardware store.

Comment: @Jasen what type of seal is this? Or is the only way to find this out by extracting it out? It is kinda chewed up so may not be easy to guess how it looked like when was new.

Comment: probably it was originally a rubber O ring, it seems kind-of mashed now,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reuse hose by just replacing the o-ring.