# O-ring, flat washer and beveled washer - are they interchangeable? What's the difference?

Tags: plumbing

I could not find a replacement water hose in the local hardware store. So I ended up [fixing the old hose](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/151208/can-i-repair-this-cold-water-hose) by replacing what appeared to be chewed flat o-washer with a brand new O-ring. I picked O-ring because the hardware store did not have flat O-washer with big enough inner diameter.

The hose is not leaking anymore with the O-ring. However, now I am wondering - when one should use beveled O-washer, flat O-washer or O-ring? Can the wrong choice lead to a leak further down the path?

Comment: The usual seal for a hose connection is a flat washer. It is OK if the inner diameter of the washer is a little smaller than the diameter of the hose. A common problem used to be that the outer diameter was too large and the washer wouldn't fit well or at all. Perhaps hardware stores stocked washers to fit the largest hoses and the idea was they could always be trimmed to fit. Then an "eared" design appeared on the market which worked well.